# Convert canvas ImageData (Uint8ClampedArray) to openCV matrix (BRG or grey) using opencv4nodejs

Tags: node.js, opencv, canvas

I would like to tranform canvas ImageData (of type Uint8ClampedArray) into a n image matrix using opencv4nodejs npm package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs

https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs#readme

The github README explains clearly how to transform an image matrix into canvas ImageData, but it does not show what methods to use for the opposite.

```
   const img = ...

// convert your image to rgba color space
const matRGBA = img.channels === 1
  ? img.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA)
  : img.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_BGR2RGBA);

// create new ImageData from raw mat data
const imgData = new ImageData(
  new Uint8ClampedArray(matRGBA.getData()),
  img.cols,
  img.rows
);
```

I would like to know how to convert a gray-scale canvas ImageData into the a matGRAY. (or a rgba ImageData into BGR matrix). Either strategy would be very helpful to me! I haven't found other documentation for this yet.

Goal:

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

//Then something like this....
// const matGRAY = opencv4nodejs.imagedata2matrix(imageData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const _ = require('lodash'); // allows fast array transformations in javascript
const Canvas = require('canvas'); //node-canvas on server side
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');
```

You can receive the Uint8ClampedArray image data from client directly
..but here we will create it from scratch.

```
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas('2d');
const ctx = getContext('2d');

const image = new Canvas.Image();
image.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0); 
}
image.src = 'path/to/image.jpg'

//get imageData from the image on our canvas
const imageDataObject = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
const imageData = imageDataObject.data;
const width = imageDataObject.width;
const height = imageDataObject.height;

//imageData is Uint8ClampedArray
```

Now that we have the Uint8ClampedArray, we can convert to matrix

```
// convert to normal array
const normalArray = Array.from(imageData);
//nest the pixel channels
const channels = 4 //canvas pixels contain 4 elements: RGBA
const nestedChannelArray = _.chunk(normalArray, channels);
const nestedImageArray = _.chunk(nestedChannelArray, height);

//nestedImageArray is the correct shape to be converted to matrix. 

const RGBAmat = new cv.Mat(nestedImageArray, cv.CV_8UC4);

//openCV often defaults to BGR-type image matrix, so lets color convert the pixel order

const BGRAmat = RGBAmat.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA);
```

BGRAmat is an openCV matrix, ready for processing!

***In case you are new to Node.js, here is the terminal code to get started.***

First, install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) then run at your terminal

```
$ mkdir canvasToMatrix
$ cd canvasToMatrix
$ npm init -y
$ npm install lodash canvas opencv4nodejs
```

Create new file.js, and paste in the code above. After saving, run

```
$ node file.js
```